# Angular: How to cache images?

Tags: javascript, angular, caching

I am developing a web app where I need to cache images so that it does not take time to load if user closes and opens website again. 
By opening website again, images should be loaded from cache instead of reloading again.

Is this possible to implement with Angular?

I searched a lot online but I did not find proper solution for that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use - **HTML manifest Attribute**

The manifest attribute specifies the location of the document's cache manifest.

HTML5 introduces application cache, which means that a web application is cached, and accessible without an internet connection.

Application cache gives an application three advantages:

- Offline browsing - users can use the application when they're offline
  Speed - cached resources load faster
- Reduced server load - the browser will only download updated/changed resources from the server
- The manifest attribute should be included on every page of your web application that you want cached.

The manifest file is a simple text file that lists the resources the browser should cache for offline access.

Detail understanding read this blog: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/