# how to cache images paths in angular 2

Tags: angular, caching

I have created an image slider. To fetch next and previous images I have created 2 functions.

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){

  this.length = this.images.length; }

getNextImage(){
    this.imageUrl = '';
    this.imageIndex++;
    if (this.imageIndex< this.length){
      this.imageUrl = this.images[this.imageIndex] 
    }
}
getPreviousImage(){
  this.imageUrl = '';
     this.imageIndex++;
       if (this.imageIndex>= 0){
          this.imageUrl = this.images[this.imageIndex] 
          }
     }
```

Every time I click on previous and next buttons the image downloads again.

Is there a way that if image is already downloaded once then it can be saved in cache?

Is this only possible with service worker?

Answer (score 1):

You can create markup for all images and show/hide images based on your condition. You may want to use [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden). 
In this case all images gets loaded in memory all at once and stays in memory until DOM is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option as decribed [in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469232/angular-how-to-cache-images), would be to use [Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)